# How to rename file name in bulk while copying it from gen1 data lake to gen2 data lake

Tags: azure-data-factory

ADF(Azure Data factory)
Requirement : Copy all the files starting with name "DATA_.parquet " available in gen1 path to gen2 path , while copying the files we have to rename the files . Replace "DATA.parquet" with "GEN2-DATA-FILE__.parquet" . Timestamp should be the old one only.

Steps I followed :

fetch all metadata available in gen1 path
Filter with filename using @statswith() function
applied for each and used copy activity
configured source and sink in copy activity
facing issue in sink I tried using replace() function for filename but its not giving any result. For each activity getting executed but I am not getting any output
filename expression I used : @replace(item.name,'DATA','GEN2-DATA-FILE')

Please let me know what expression I should use to achieve the result

Answer (score 0):

To rename file name while copying it from gen1 data lake to gen2 data lake you need to us proper dynamic expression:

Here, I have some files in Azure data lake gen 1 as below:

[image]

Then I fetched the files from the path with get metadata activity.

[image]

Then I passed this output to foreach activity with items value `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

[image]

After this I passed the value of foreach to the file name in source

[image]

and then in sink file name add dynamic content to replace the filename with expression `@replace(item().name,'file','GEN2-DATA-FILE')`

[image]

**OUTPUT :**

**File name changed from `file1` to `GEN2-DATA-FILE1`:**

[image]